# Simple DOM file_get_html returns not work

Tags: html, dom

i want to get google search results with simple html dom but not work

```
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$q = $_GET['q'];
$url  = 'http://google.com/search?hl=en&as_epq='.urlencode($q).'&cr=countryIR&as_qdr=all&as_occt=any&safe=active';
echo file_get_html($url);
```

this code worked in my localhost but not work in host